# Windows10 Technical Preview の VirtualBox へのインストールが完了出来ません

Tags: windows, virtualbox

WindowsTechnicalPreview-9879-x64-EN-US.iso を,
VirtualBox v4.3.10 r93012(Mac) にインストールしたいのですが,
インストール中に「Getting ready」というメッセージが出る画面から先に進みません.

仮装マシンの設定は,

- OS:Windows8.1(64bit)
- メモリ:4096MB
- ビデオメモリ:64MB
- ストレージ:SATAコントローラ, 20GB SSD

という感じです.
設定など気をつける点などあればお教え頂きたく存じます.
よろしくお願いします.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Change log](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog)に

> VirtualBox 4.3.18 (released 2014-10-10)
>
> - Windows Additions: some Windows 10 tweaks

とありますので、最新版で試してみてはどうでしょうか。

---

あとで試しに最新版にいれてみるつもりですので、VirtualBoxの入れ替えに少し躊躇するようであれば私の結果を待ってみてもいいかもしれません :)

---

## 追記

VirtualBox v4.3.20とWindowsTechnicalPreview-9879-x64-EN-US.isoを双方ともに先ほどDLして

ゲスト設定

- OS:Windows8.1(64bit)
- メモリ:4096MB
- ストレージ：変更なし（25GBになってました）
- ビデオメモリ:変更なし（アクセラレーションはどちらもチェックついていませんが、ビデオメモリは128MB）

で、インストールできました。

ビデオメモリの部分のみ画面ショットを載せておきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一応参考までにGetting readyのあと再起動がかかり、ユーザー作成の手前でネットワーク無効にしてローカルアカウント作成でインストール完了させました。